# Taxes Database Schema

Tags: php, mysql, database, e-commerce, laravel

I'm trying to determine the most appropriate way to store taxes for products.

```
TABLE products (
    id
    name
    description
)

TABLE tax_zones (
    id
    code
)

TABLE tax_rates (
    id
    zone_id
    rate
)

TABLE tax (
    id
    rate_id
)

TABLE product_tax (
    id
    product_id
    tax_id
)
```

I'll admit, even I'm a little confused by this structure, so I'm needing some help to either simplify or clarify or both.

My shop is international, so it's just for Canada and the US... products can be bought all over the world.

Comment: You can try to draw the scheme on paper, you'll figure out it easier.

Comment: Oh, I have... I'm just needing some fresh eyes on the situation. And I need to make sure that I'm doing it right.

Comment: Better to post on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is there every columns there? The `tax` table seems redundant.

Comment: what are your local tax obligations?

Comment: @didierc that's what I was thinking too...

Comment: "Local" is irrelevant when it comes to tax. Tax should be applied according to the country, state, region, county, town, etc. that the item is being 'shipped' to. In other words, it's the recipient's tax rules that are applicable. If a product is a gift to someone in a region other than that of the purchaser, it is their tax rules that apply. In other words, the buyer pays the tax that applies to the person receiving the gift!

Answer (score 2):

What is the purpose of the table `product_tax`? Storing tax information for each product is not the way you should go.

Taxes in the US (and probably Canada) vary from state to state, are usually down to the ZIP code level (and sometimes even sub-ZIP!). The proper way to handle taxes is to apply them to the whole shopping cart (i.e. calculated from a percentage), not on individual products.

As to how you deal with taxes... welcome to the fun world of online shopping. There are some services out there that provide web services (because taxes change very frequently). One such product is [AvaTax](http://www.avalara.com/products/avatax).

I'll reiterate what I said in my comment. Having built many shopping carts (and having been burned in the process!) I have considerable experience in the field.

> "Local" is irrelevant when it comes to tax. Tax should be applied
>   according to the country, state, region, county, town, etc. that the
>   item is being 'shipped' to. In other words, it's the recipient's tax
>   rules that are applicable. If a product is a gift to someone in a
>   region other than that of the purchaser, it is their tax rules that
>   apply. In other words, the buyer pays the tax that applies to the
>   person receiving the gift!

Additionally, I'll elucidate my comment below a little further...

Tax is completely separate from the products concerned. Tax should be applied to the full cost amount, not to individual items. The only exception is where a product has been deemed as "non-taxable". This mostly applies to certain food items that are considered "essentials". Apparently, everything else is deemed a luxury!

So, if three $1 items are in the cart, a tax rate of 8.00% would be applied to bring the total to $3.24. Any shipping costs would be added **after** the tax is applied. Shipping is not part of the product price and is therefore not taxable (shipping costs are pre-taxed by FedEx, UPS, etc.).

Because tax rates vary geographically, it makes no sense to try to attach a 'tax' value to a product in a database. That data should be applied separately, on every single transaction. Getting the correct tax amounts from a web service reduces the possibility of making an error. It's important to note that taxes change frequently. If you are audited and proven to have charged the incorrect tax you may be required to pay the difference yourself. Tax law rarely cares **who** pays the tax, only that it is paid.

Okay, so some ideas regarding table structure...

```
product table {
    id
    sku [manufacturer or made up]
    related_items
    brand
    description
    features
    specifications                           
    keywords
    price
    weight
    width
    height
    length
    packaging_type
    shipping_info
    flatrate_shipping
    taxable
    discountable
    insured
    featured
    status [enum('outofstock','instock','specialorder','calltoorder','comingsoon','onorder','sold','onhold','hide')]
    stock
}

category table {
    id
    category_id
    category_name
    category_description
}

product_category table {
    id
    category_id
    product_id
}
```

The last table provides a way to put many products into a category, or one product into many.

Comment: Certainly don't want to have tax per product... but isn't there some kind of information that I need to attach to a product?

Comment: Yes and no... Except that some products are deemed "untaxable" by certain territories. The list of what is and isn't taxable varies to some degree, but by-and-large, most items are taxable. If this applies to your store, use a flag in the product table to indicate taxable or not. Other than that, it's a simple matter of multiplying the cart total (before shipping costs) by the tax percentage. If you have a mixture of taxable and non-taxable items that can be purchased together, simply divide into two buckets and apply the tax percentage to one.

Comment: This answer is great... I'm watching it as you update it. Can I perhaps pick your brain for a brief moment elsewhere (like Skype or within a stackoverflow discussion? I need to really get a sense of what my tables should look like.

Comment: It's kind of awkward right now, but I want to help. I added some database schema ideas into my answer. I hope that inspires! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Taxes can depend on very different things, depending on the legal situation:

- Seller's location
- Buyer's location
- Product (type)

Any combination is possible. E.g., in Germany there are (simplified) 7% on food and 19% on non-food products, if both seller and buyer are in Europe.

Other rules may come. Taxes could be time-based, for example.

So, in the end, you need a tax key going with your product (or the product group), and a tax table indexed by tax_key, seller_location, and buyer_location. Using wildcards for the latter two, you can reduce the number of records needed.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Tax should be applied per shipping destination AND per product because you can have products with different taxs rate in the same cart.